# Can libuv run in (mobile) game client's main loop?

Tags: multithreading, lua, cocos2d-x, libuv

I'm searching for a network library for mobile game client side networking.

I'm currently using **cocos2d-x** with **Lua** for client side programming.

I'm consider use libuv or [luv](https://github.com/luvit/luv) (a Lua binding for libuv) in my client side networking library (TCP).

Running libuv loop in **UV_RUN_ONCE** or **UV_RUN_NOWAIT** mode each frame in game main loop (main thread). When libuv received networking data, it calls my callback Lua functions in game main thread (where the Lua VM runs), and my Lua code decrypt and decode and process the message.

My question is:

1. will libuv make my game mainloop slow and drop my fps when networking traffic goes up (of course when within a reasonable message size and amount)?
2. need I put libuv loop in another thread and wrap the callback delay called my Lua functions in main thread?

Comment: Honestly I have no idea, but if it's a well known library I'm doubting it'll be THAT bad... Why not test it yourself?

Comment: Did you figure this out ? I would like to host a UDP server within my cocos2d-x (c++) iOS game as well and was looking for some sample code for this.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can with UV_RUN_NOWAIT, it will run any every queued event in the event loop with it and if there are none, it will just return.

UV_RUN_ONCE for example will bock until there is at least one event in the queue.

Comment: Yes, jsut run with with UV_RUN_NOWAIT in the event loop somewhere